# DOM element (div1) was performing an jquery animation and DOM element is deleted on manual event e.g. click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

DOM element (div1) was performing an jquery animation and DOM element is deleted on manual event e.g. click

what will happen in this case?

Comment: did you try and see what happens?

Comment: i tried ...it was working fine... but i am bit confused whether do we need to stop event or it will be automatically handled...

Comment: My guess is once an element is removed... So is the event so there's no need to handle anything..

Answer (score 0):

There isn't actually a way to directly delete a DOM element.  You can remove it from the DOM (with `.removeChild()`) and clear your references to it.  Only when there are no other references to that DOM element will the garbage collector actually get rid of it some time later.

But, if there's an animation running on it, that animation will have a reference to it preventing the garbage collector from actually deleting it and the animation will likely continue until its completion.  If it has been removed from the DOM, you won't see the effects of the animation any more because it isn't visible when not in the DOM, but it's properties are still being animated.

When the animation finishes and the reference to it is released because the animation closure reference is cleared out of the animation queue, then the garbage collector will finally be free to actually delete the element.

FYI, if you want, you can call `.stop(true)` on any animating jQuery object to stop its current animation.

Comment: thanks... i am using $("parentDiv").html("") to remove all DOM element; if i am using jquery  plugin for image slider, so to remoe references i need to stop any timer or events also.? 
thanks for information.